# kilobytes to human readable. Looking for one liner

Tags: perl, sed, awk, sh, du

I often work on unix boxes that don't have the -h flag for du.

I am looking for a one-liner to convert KB to human readable. Perl seemed like a good choice.

This is what I have so far.

```
@a=split /\s+/;
$x=$_!=0?int(log()/log(1024)):0;
@b=('K','M','G');
printf("%.3s%s\t%s\n",$_/(1024)**$x,$b[$x],$a[1]);
```

Run like this:

```
du -ks * | perl -lne '@a=split /\s+/;$x=$_!=0?int(log()/log(1024)):0;@b=('K','M','G');printf("%.3s%s\t%s\n",$_/(1024)**$x,$b[$x],$a[1]);'
```

It doesn't work perfectly as I haven't been able to find the correct printf format.

one-liners using perl as well as awk/sed, etc. would be the most useful.

This is what du -h looks like. Max 1 decimal. Min: 0 decimals. With Rounding.

```
8.0K
1.7M
4.0M
5.7M
88K
```

Update:

```
du -ks * | perl -lane '$F[0];$x=$_!=?int(log()/log(1024)):0;printf("%.3s%s\t%s\n",$_/1024**$x,qw<K M G>[$x],$F[1]);'
```

Comment: good tip. I will update the OP in a second.

Comment: After a bit of research, it looks like this can't be done with just a single standard printf specifier; cf. `prthumanval` in [the Mac OS X implementation of `du`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-212/du/du.c), which has separate cases depending on whether the number to display is above 10 or not.

Comment: you're missing 0 in your updated oneliner, should be "$_ != 0",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only modification you want to make (It's not clear what you want) is to have the number be right-aligned in a field of 3 characters, simply drop the period from the printf format.  Also, rather than explicitly calling `split` and treating the whole of `$_` as a number, I would recommend passing Perl the `-a` switch, which automatically splits `$_` on whitespace into the array `@F`, and then replace the references to `$_` in your code with `$F[0]`.

Your code could thus be rewritten (using a couple more Perlisms and adding some spaces for readability) as:

```
du -ks * | perl -lane '$x = $F[0] != 0 && int(log($F[0])/log(1024)); printf("%3d%s\t%s\n", $F[0]/1024**$x, qw<K M G>[$x], $F[1]);'
```

Comment: I want it to look like du -hs *. Also, The way we're using %s, it just cuts off characters, it doesn't round or anything.

Comment: What if file name in `$F[1]` has spaces/tabs?

Answer (score 4):

This uses `Number::Bytes::Human` from CPAN:

```
du -ks * |perl -MNumber::Bytes::Human=format_bytes -nle \
    '@F=split(/\s+/,$_,2); printf("%-10s%s\n", format_bytes($F[0]*1024), $F[1])'
```

EDIT: Without using modules:

```
du -ks * |perl -nle \
   '@F=split(/\s+/,$_,2); $b=$F[0]*1024; for($i=0;$b>1024;$i++){$b/=1024} $u=qw{B K M G T}[$i]; printf("%10.".($b=~/\./?1:0)."f$u  %s\n", $b, $F[1])'
```

Comment: Good idea, but sadly: 'Can't locate Number/Bytes/Human.pm in @INC'. Also, good thinking on the files with spaces.

Comment: @user606723: right, it's not part of the core Perl installation. You would need to download it from CPAN.

Comment: Yeah, but that defeats the purpose of the one liner. The whole point is to have a script I can "install" and run by copying and pasting thats it.

Comment: @user606723 - Well, if you install the module then you can use that one liner as many times as you want.  That's one of the main ideas behind modules:  highly reusable code.

Comment: Install it on 20+ boxes I don't have root to? Again, it's not feasible in this situation.

Comment: @user606723 - It is entirely feasible:  http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/local-lib-1.008004/lib/local/lib.pm and/or http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.30/lib/App/perlbrew.pm

Comment: If you can't install CPAN modules then you're not using most of the power of Perl. As for installing it across 20+ hosts - why aren't you using something like puppet?

Comment: People don't seem to be understanding that they aren't my hosts. I have no interest in installing modules on them.

Answer (score 3):

```
du -sk * | perl -ane '
  $i=0;
  while ($F[0]>1024) {$F[0]/=1024; $i++}; 
  printf("%d%s\t%s\n", $F[0], qw(K M G)[$i], $F[1])
'
```

If you want fractions on the bigger numbers:

```
du -sk * | perl -ane '
  $i=0;
  while ($F[0]>1024) {$F[0]/=1024; $i++;};
  $f = $i==0 ? "d" : ".2f"; 
  printf("%$f%s\t%s\n", $F[0], qw(K M G)[$i], $F[1])
'
```

Answer (score 2):

your correct printf() format:

```
sub get_filesize_str
{
    my $file = shift;

    my $size = (stat($file))[7] || die "stat($file): $!\n";

    if ($size > 1099511627776) {   #   TiB: 1024 GiB
        return sprintf("%.2f TiB", $size / 1099511627776);
    } elsif ($size > 1073741824) { #   GiB: 1024 MiB
        return sprintf("%.2f GiB", $size / 1073741824);
    } elsif ($size > 1048576) {    #   MiB: 1024 KiB
        return sprintf("%.2f MiB", $size / 1048576);
    } elsif ($size > 1024) {       #   KiB: 1024 B
        return sprintf("%.2f KiB", $size / 1024);
    } else {                       #   bytes
        return sprintf("%.2f bytes", $size);
    }
}
```

that's not my code, it was taken from [here](http://www.use-strict.de/articles/Perl__Filesize_in_a_human_readable_format.html)

Comment: I've already tried that.. it pads .00 at the end of everything.. which is kind of annoying.

Comment: You can always pass it through `s/\.00$//`.

Comment: it's better to make a perl script which will contain logic and it's description rather than do everything by one ugly line :)

Comment: @user973254, typically yes, but being able to transfer the script my copy and paste better in this case.. There are too many boxes and too many logins to move it to everyone of them...

Comment: %.0f doesn't work either because then their will be no decimal places. Updated op with example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is AWK function adapted from some answer on stackoverflow:

```
function human_readable(sum) {

hum[1024**3]="GiB";hum[1024**2]="MiB";hum[1024]="KiB"; 
    for (x=1024**3; x>=1024; x/=1024){ 
        if (sum>=x) { v = sprintf( "%.2f %s",sum/x,hum[x]); return v }
    }
}
```